# MS Access WhereConditions in xml export

Tags: sql, xml, ms-access, report, where-clause

I'm trying make an XML export of Report. 
It works, but I cant make filter criteria. I want to filter by `DATE`, 4 months to the past.

```
Dim sXMLPath As String

sXMLPath = "z://export1.xml" ExportXML acExportReport, "export1",
sXMLPath, , , , , , [DATUM] > Date - 120 And [DATUM] <= Date 
MsgBox"DONE"

End Sub
```

This exports all reports.

I have no idea if the field DATUM loaded correctly.

Export of a single column looks like this:

```
<export1>
<CISLO_VYKRESU>D3573</CISLO_VYKRESU>
<VYMENY_ZMENOU>914999</VYMENY_ZMENOU>
<zmeny_ZMENOU>914999</zmeny_ZMENOU>
<DATUM>2001-01-01T00:00:00</DATUM>
<POPIS>TEXTEXTETX</POPIS>
<STROJ>W5555</STROJ>
<DUVOD>SOME</DUVOD>
<ZMENOU>914999</ZMENOU>
<ZMENOU_VYMENY>914999</ZMENOU_VYMENY>
</export1>
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im allready found answer. 
Create your own Report with filter, make export and at end just save moves (I dont know how it is in Eng lang).

Than make makro DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport "NAME-saved"

Thats all :)